# Does the word "general" refers to both requirement and design consideration in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Here is the name of a chapter of the book I was reading named "Design Of Small Canal Structures":

> Chapter 1 - General Requirements and Design Consideration

I'm wondering if the word "general" refers to both "requirements" and "design consideration" or not? I think it refers to both of them but have no clue why? And also can we make a similar sentence (or adjust the mentioned one) so that the word general refers to only the next word(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's example text is ambiguous - only context can tell us whether the scope of that initial modifier extends beyond the first noun in such constructions. To illustrate the point more clearly, ask yourself the same question with...

> 1: *There were only old men and women in the park*
> 2: *There were only old men and children in the park*

Unless there's something *very* unusual about the context, we can take it for granted the women are *also* old in #1, but *not* the children in #2.

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party but, thanks for the advises that you've provided in comments below the other answer. Sometimes, I have problem in understanding a phrase or a part of English text. As an example please check [my recent post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340433/what-does-learned-to-know-mean-in-i-soon-learned-to-know-that-flower-better). In this situation how could I realize the meaning of the phrase without help of experienced users? I searched on google and dictionaries and found no relevant result.

Comment: I acknowledge the importance of being independent in reading and understanding the meaning of a text. And I usually do understand by looking up the Oxford or Longman dictionaries. But I think there are exceptions too. And I believe that learners should sometimes challenge themselves. For example one wouldn't progress much if they read only intermediate level English stories/texts.

Comment: Your question about Le Petit Prince just goes to show that you should probably try to avoid using *translated* texts as an aid to learning English. The cited use of *to **learn** to know* wasn't particularly unusual in English a century or two ago (and I believe the original French is still perfectly natural). But as comments to your question indicate, it's no longer idiomatic for *current* Anglophones. With something like that, try [searching for the relevant text in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22soon+learned+to+know%22), to see the same words in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Titles like this can often seem ambiguous, as titles are often kept very brief.  I feel you might be trying to read too much into this TBH. The rest of the chapter would doubtless clear up any ambiguity.

From the wording, I would assume that **General** modifies the whole title, unless the context of the following paragraph indicates otherwise. Context is everything. However, if that isn't what the writer intended, it could easily have been rearranged as **Design Consideration and General Requirements**, but they chose not to word it like that.

Comment: I don't think there's really much point in suggesting to OP which reading *you* think should apply in this specific case. If it's *semantically* obvious, the OP can work it out for himself - once he's been told that the *syntax* is ambiguous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Counterpoint, it's often very frustrating when you ask a question about meaning and the only answer you get is 'it's ambiguous' - especially if you asked because someone else has a more complete understanding of the topic than you do.

Comment: @RyanJensen:  I always tend to assume "questions about meaning" are mostly trivial. If you can't understand the text you're reading without help from an online Q&A site, you're probably reading text that's not suitable for you in the first place (you're not part of the target readership). I see ELL as a site dedicated to helping people learn *how English works* (neologisms, syntactic structures, idioms, ambiguous constructions, etc.). Vocabulary people can pick up from dictionaries - and if an ambiguity is context-dependent, the OP knows that context better than us *because he's reading it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would consider the name 'English Language Learners' to suggest the site is intended to answer questions related to or arising from learning English. A main way you improve your reading level - whether native or learning ESL - is by reading texts that are at the top of or just past your comprehension level. 
That said, I acknowledge you have much more experience than me on this site, so I'm not going to claim my interpretation must be right.

Comment: I might have more experience than you on this site, but I don't necessarily know much about TEFL in general. A *long* time ago, I spent a year in France as part of my degree, but I honestly doubt I ever asked a French person what some passage in a book meant. If I saw a word often enough, and I couldn't get the meaning from context, I might have consulted my trusty Harraps, but mostly I learned French the same way I learned English - just listen to people talking, and try to copy them.