# What does "learned to know" mean in "I soon learned to know that flower better"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading the Little Prince story by St. Exupery. The first sentence of chapter 8 is:

> I soon learned to know that flower better.

I'm not sure about the meaning of the above sentence. Does that mean, I soon learned how to know that flower better and the narrator learned the way of knowing the flower better?

Comment: It is grammatical but not idiomatic English.  Idiomatic would be **come to know**, **came to know**.

Comment: "J'appris bien vite à mieux connaître cette fleur."

Comment: The speaker soon became better acquainted with the flower. Note that this is a translation from the French.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Note that *I [soon **got to know**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learned+to+know%2Ccame+to+know%2Cgot+to+know&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) that flower better* is the most likely auxiliary verb in this context.